# Writing a NoSQL / MongoDB Driver

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, common-lisp

I am currently thinking of undertaking the task specified in the title for one of the Lisp languages (most likely Common Lisp). However, I have no idea about what is involved.

Hence, I am asking this question. What are the steps for writing a DB driver in general and MongoDB driver in particular? Having briefly looked for some tutorials, it appears that there is a bit of a dearth in that realm.

Could someone point me to some resources on this? Does MongoDB have documentation/API on this?

P.S. If this question is better suited for another Stackexchange site, I will be happy to move it.

Comment: If you don’t know Lisp then start with something easy. Otherwise look into a C api for mongo and use your implementation’s ffi or use CFFI (that’s Common FFI not the python project by the same name). If mongo doesn’t have a C api then maybe there’s a Java api you could use from ABCL. Or maybe there’s a text/binary protocol you need to implement. No one writes a tutorial on “how to write an interface to a database”. The steps are: 1) know the language, 2) know the database, 3) know C, 4) look into C or binary APIs for the database, 5) decide how to implement your api, 6) implement it.

Comment: What do you think of [cl-mongo](https://github.com/fons/cl-mongo) ? ([awesome-cl#database](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#database)). You also have libraries for redis, rethinkdb, couchdb if that's of interest.

Comment: @Ehvince it appears outdated and unsupported to me. I am considering Redis and other NoSQL. The problem is that I already have a back-end written in Node that is using Mongo and would just like to implement it in Lisp, if possible.

Comment: @DanRobertson I believe it is the step 4) that I am asking about here.

Comment: I believe I was after this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/

Comment: @MadPhysicist you might want to take a look at https://github.com/mongodb/specifications where the specifications for MongoDB drivers are defined.

Comment: You might want to check out SWIG. Have not used it for a while, but it made wrapping c libraries pretty easy